# c# Set property of customattribute

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, custom-attributes

I have created a custom class named AttributeConfiguration with the following attributes.

```
public class AttributeConfiguration : Attribute
{
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string SchemaNameCRM { get; set; }
        public string SchemaNameERP { get; set; }
        public bool Required { get; set; }
        public bool IsChild { get; set; }
}
```

I have some other class that decorates its properties with my custom class AttributeConfiguration.

```
public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
          //Here I want to set all properties of my custom attribute 
          //AttributeConfiguration that decorates my attribute CODE
    }

    [AttributeConfiguration()]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I need to set the properties of the custom class AttributeConfiguration which is decorating my attribute code in the constructor of my Client entity.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
//PROPERTY OF MY CLASS
 var property = this.GetType().GetProperty("Code");

//MY CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE CONFIGURATOIN
AttributeConfiguration propertyConfigurationBeforeChange = property.GetCustomAttributes(false)
.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(AttributeConfiguration)).FirstOrDefault() as AttributeConfiguration;

 //GET SchemaNameERP from my Custom AttributeConfiguration instance
 PropertyInfo propertySchemaNameERP = propertyConfigurationBeforeChange.GetType().GetProperty("SchemaNameERP");
//CHANGING DEFAULT VALUE = Default Value is "ValueNotApplied"
propertySchemaNameERP.SetValue(propertyConfigurationBeforeChange, "NEW VALUE", null);

//SchemaNameERP property of my custom class instance propertyConfigurationBeforeChange has changed to my NEW VALUE 

  ///GETTING VALUE OF MY CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE CONFIGURATOIN FOR THE SECOND TIME AND IT HASN'T CHANGED THE DEFAULT VALUE
  attributeConfiguration propertyConfigurationAfterChange = property.GetCustomAttributes(false)
   .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(AttributeConfiguration)).FirstOrDefault() as AttributeConfiguration;
```

In this example I am trying to change the value only of the property SchemaNameERO, however I am able only to change the value of the atrribute of the instance I have created (propertyConfigurationBeforeChange variable), but not in the actual instance which "is within" the property Code.

I am stuck with that whole day.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: That's not exactly like changing the return type of a method at runtime, but it's in the ballpark. You can't do that and you shouldn't be able to. What are you trying to accomplish by doing it?

Comment: I am working on an integration of two systems, this Client class is my system A, I am using this custom attribute to automatically map this class to another object, this way, I have to save in those customattributes the destination of the property.

Comment: Well, you'll have to find some other way to do it that's actually possible. Setting the attribute values in the source code, for example.

Comment: By the way Ed, I didn't understand why you said "That's not exactly like changing the return type of a method at runtime". Sorry if i missunderstood you, but for me it's not, I mean, I am trying to set the value properties of a class, I didn't mean to change its properties types.

Comment: You're trying to change something that was set permanently -- and globally -- at compile time. It's essentially part of the definition of the class.

Comment: I am able to set it while Im decorating the property, I.E    [AttributeConfiguration(_DisplayName: "My Code", _Required: true, _SchemaNameCRM: "tz_cep_entregaid")]
    public string Code {get;set;}

Why wouldn't I be able to change, for instance, "My Code" to "My Code changed"

Comment: Yes, that's how they're designed to be used.